# ArrayType(StringType) to IntegerType conversion in spark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to `groupBy` column name `host` and aggregate average of a column of type `ArrayType(StringType)` after type casting it to `ArrayType(IntegerType)`.

It throws below error

```
 `cannot resolve `avg(variables)` due to datatype mismatch: function average requires numeric types, not ArrayType(IntegerType,true);
```

Input Data - sample Dataframe before grouping

```
|request|time         |type   |host |service       |    variables      |
|REST   |1542111483170|RESTFUL|KAFKA|www.google.com|[Duration, 7,Type] |
|REST   |1542111486570|RESTFUL|KAFKA|www.google.com|[Duration, 9, Type]|
```

How to cast or handle ArrayType(StringType) to IntegerType i.e Column variables is of `ArrayType(varaible.variable:String,varaible.value:String,varaible.TypeString)` I want to convert 2nd value of Array `varaible.value` to Integer for Aggregation (Average calculation)?

Case Class:

```
 case class ServiceActivity(val request: String, val time: Long, val Type: String, val host: String, val service: String, val variables: Array[Variables])

 case class Variables(val variable: String, val value: String, val Type: String)
```

Code Below:

```
val report = df.select("*").where(array_contains(df("variables.variable"),"Duration"))
val intermediate = report.withColumn("variables", col(variables.value).cast(org.apache.spark.sql.types.ArrayType(org.apache.spark.sql.types.IntegerType,true)
intermediate.withColumn("duration",$"variables".getItem(2)).drop("variables").withColumnRenamed("duration","variables")
```

GroupBy Code(error):

```
 intermediate.groupBy(intermediate("host")).agg(Map("variables"->"avg"))
```

Any workarounds.

Thanks

Comment: can you share the schema of dataframe `df` ?

Comment: Question Updated

Comment: @ShankarKoirala, Any Updates.

Comment: Could you add more detials on how you are inputing Variables dataframe and combining it with ServiceActivity dataframe? Sample code and data would be helpful to replicate the problem.

Comment: Can you please update in detail with input data and required output data

Comment: Thank you @ShankarKoirala  for the response.

Comment: Thank you @user238607 and sorry for the unclear explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Sorted out by splitting the Array and using `concat_ws` method

```
  val splitArray = ab.withColumn("Avg_Duration", concat_ws("", ab("variables.value")))

  splitArray.groupBy(splitArray("host")).agg(Map("Avg_Duration" -> "avg")).show(false)
```

Thank you